# Cloud9 Run Option Computes Twice As Fast, But Takes Longer To Display Output On Terminal

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud9-ide, aws-cloud9

While AWS Cloud9 (C9) IDE's **Run**[Alt+F5] option runs Python programs (py) **twice faster** then a competing compute engine, but C9 takes *almost thrice longer* to display output on C9's terminal, so the time advantage is lost.
However if I compile/run the same py on the C9's terminal using **`python[2-3] my_simple_program.py`**, it shows the output instantly, after compilation.
The problem is only when displaying outputs of **Run**[Alt+F5] option on C9's IDE, which I would prefer to use.
The py code:

```
# my_simple_program.py

import time

class many_items:
    def __init__(self):
        self._many_random_names = [ 
                'Vladimir Alexandrakis',
                'Zampeta Bekiaris',
                'Triantafyl Tsatsos',
                'Melpomeni Papantoniou',
                'Korina Angelis',
                'Manolis Karatzas',
                'Niki Kostas',
                'Venetia Symeonidis',
                'Kassiani Kritikou',
                'Maria Stavrou'
                ]

    def __getitem__(self, arg1):
        print('__getitem__() called with argument: ' + str(arg1))
        return self._many_random_names[arg1]

    def __setitem__(self, arg1, arg2):
        print('__setitem__() called with arguments: ' +
              str(arg1) + ' and ' + arg2)
        self._many_random_names[arg1] = arg2
        return self._many_random_names[arg1]

# Timing
start_time = time.time()

m_items = many_items()
print(m_items[8])  # Calls __getitem__(8)
# !Calls __setitem__(8,'Nikolina Kavvadias') and passes two arguments 8 and 'Nikolina Kavvadias' plus self
m_items[8] = 'Nikolina Kavvadias'
print(m_items[8])

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

#AWS: < 0.0002923011779785156 secs
#Competitor: > 5.650520324707031e-05 secs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this timelag issue by using `nodemon`!
Now I have the amazing mix of **C9** and blazing fast results too!
Woohoo!